How can I redirect user to different URL without changing the URL in address bar using NetScaler
I have a URL:- https://abc.test.com and I want it to redirect to https://app.xyz.com/groups/fjedkk&hlo=hji by keeping https://abc.test.com in the address bar of the user using Netscaler policies
I tried creating some responder policy and it is getting redirected but its also showing in address bar which is not the feasible solution for me
